# Azure account disabled, anyway to get a database backup?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I got a new job and my former company has disabled my Microsoft account before I could do a backup of my Azure database. Now I can't log into Azure anymore.

I still have a website running on Azure, but I giess it will be put down soon. Is there a way to get a backup of my Azure database before it is totally removed ?

The database is still running. I tried to log into the database via SSMS but since I have a new computer in a new home, my new IP is not whitelisted on the Azure dashboard...

And I can't create support ticket for I cannot log in anymore.

Any idea ?

Comment: This is not a topic for stackoverlfow. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You'll need to contact your former employer.

Comment: Since you mentioned that your website is still working, I'm assuming that firewall rules are configured properly to allow access to services running in Azure. If that's the case, create a new Azure Subscription, stand up a VM there, install SSMS in it and connect to your database from there. Give it a try. This should work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question

Answer (score -3):

Ask your employer to add your IP to the database? Or create a backup for you. There is not other way to get access to the azure database without subscription account.